# What does COM port mean?

Tags: networking

When I connect my phone to my computer via USB cable, it displays 'Mass Storage and COM port'. Selecting Mass storage enables me to send and collect files but I have no idea what COM port does. Does it perhaps have something to do with networking?

Comment: ***COM** port* used to be a reference to a _RS-232 serial communications port_, used for connecting telephone modems to computers more years ago than I care to admit being involved with computers for. It is entirely possible that it is now an _emulated_ serial communications port, or just a generic _communications_ port.

Comment: What phone exactly are we talking about? // Yes, the COM port was used to talk to modems in the past.

Comment: I'm guessing that you are relatively new to computers. It stands for COMmunication port. Also, google could have told you that faster than typing the question here.

Comment: For what it's worth, RS232 serial communications ports were also used to connect some printers to the computer, and were occasionally used (e.g., by an old program called LapLink) to establish direct computer-to-computer communications.

Comment: Yes, I actually googled it up but I didn't get the answer I needed. My phone is actually a java based phone. I thought selecting the COM port option will enable me to access the internet through the data on my phone.

Comment: What you are asking for is generally called tethering. Your phone plan needs to allow it and your phone needs to be built to do it. If your question was not "What does COM port mean?" then you should not ask that question.

Comment: Okay, sorry if I'm bothering you guys but if I can infact do networking over a COM port, how do I set it up?

Comment: Call your service provider first and make sure that tethering is enabled for your account. They can probably walk you through setting it up if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

Com ports (communication ports) are usually serial bit rate interfaces. (Classically 9600 Baud) In most cases when someone is referring to a com-port, they are referencing a db-9 (RS-232) or db-25 connection.

They are still extremely important in regards to configuring Enterprise network equipment. Before Enterprise routers, switches, firewalls etc have interfaces configured, most (if not all?) need to be configured first with console access. RS-232 via roll-over cable. (Some newer models have emulated serial via usb)

They are still widely used in micro controllers as a standardized way to communicate chip to chip. Btw, you can still use old U.S robotics modems to have arduinos dial each other and communicate over the PSTN. Each device is essentially blind to the modem, and operates as if the two were directly connected on a workbench.

In most phones they are emulated ports. But in some are a way to establish communications with the GPS, Data, and sometimes the phone OS directly.

A good example is the software GPSgate, this allows you to use the com-port on a phone to forward GPS information to another device. On the computer side, you can mirror the com-port to as many emulated ports as you wish. Allowing you to run as many GPS driven applications as you want, and each program thinks it has exclusive access to it's own GPS unit.

Answer (score 0):

COM ports are Windows terminology (borrowed from DOS which was borrowed from CPM) for a serial port.  A serial port lets two devices talk with a minimum of setup and fuss, but not at a very high speed, and the protocol for real serial ports (RS-232) is old (goes back to the 50s), well established, and not encumbered by patents or other IP laws.

The USB stack of many operating systems supports a number of built-in standard "class" drivers for USB devices.

Mass storage is one of these.  So any USB flash drive or hard drive will use this built in "USB mass storage driver" and you don't have to install a driver for any USB storage devices, typically.

Serial or "COM" ports are another USB class that has standard drivers in most operating systems.

USB-to-serial converters are the obvious devices that would use this, but any USB device can make itself look like a standard device to an operating system, and as long as the device responds properly, things will work.

Phones use serial or "COM" ports for various reasons:

- High-quality dial-up modems are connected via serial ports.  Some phones provide a modem-like interface over a COM port.  These would likely be older phones.
- There's a standard where a GPS receiver can deliver location info over a serial port.
- Some phones have a debug interface available over a COM port.  It might be used to reflash or update a phone's firmware or access other service modes.

You can do networking over a COM port but don't want to because of the low speed.

There are "Ethernet" or "RNDIS" USB class drivers as well, so there's not much stopping a device from offering what looks like an Ethernet port on top of all this, and that's something phones can do as well.